# Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid)

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I am recreating a hyperledger fabric network.

I have deleted all the docker volumes,docker images related to the chaincode, docker container, and services.

Yet, I am receiving this error on channel creation.

This is a multi-host network running in 2 machines. When I try to run in one machine, it works fine.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

```
2018-12-21 10:43:43.490 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 539 Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid) for identity 0a046672656512ed052d2d2d2d2d424547494e2043455254494649434154452d2d2d2d2d0a4d4949422b7a434341614b6741774942416749554e2b64656779745849376b5a7336654f5551384c4775345447525177436759494b6f5a497a6a3045417749770a6254454c4d416b474131554542684d4356564d78457a415242674e5642416754436b4e6862476c6d62334a7561574578466a415542674e564241635444564e680a62694247636d467559326c7a59323878466a415542674e5642416f5444575a795a5755755a6e4a6c5a53356a623230784754415842674e5642414d5445474e680a4c6d5a795a5755755a6e4a6c5a53356a623230774868634e4d5467784d6a49784d54417a4e4441775768634e4d546b784d6a49784d54417a4f544177576a41680a4d513877445159445651514c45775a6a62476c6c626e5178446a414d42674e5642414d544257466b62576c754d466b77457759484b6f5a497a6a3043415159490a4b6f5a497a6a304441516344516741457a725a6f4e6650784c767558327a612b366a4c3748684c3942334e725a76423232444f79326f7a59786e6e4f315043340a53686a4b3034497759506543536d4538424b7444587a676c454c596d52766e354f4251634b714e734d476f7744675944565230504151482f42415144416765410a4d41774741315564457745422f7751434d414177485159445652304f4242594546456c75543553586e6d764c66704748374c5a4e5032437673736b374d4373470a413155644977516b4d434b41494f753557775139545a556e724847316270455a3953426f32756166677279443733354c4d54346a6259785a4d416f47434371470a534d343942414d43413063414d455143494436545769482f74384c3175795a77624a453754713171704f324e4f4e6731747252326e372f4461492b474169416a0a677a767350476c5853764e4c7937486f4c492f3135755535335179505861577275782b7a327970336b413d3d0a2d2d2d2d2d454e442043455254494649434154452d2d2d2d2d0a

2018-12-21 10:43:43.491 UTC [common/deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 53a [channel: jan] Client authorization revoked for deliver request from 10.255.0.3:42796: Failed evaluating policy on signed data during check policy on channel [jan] with policy [/Channel/Application/Readers]: [Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining]
```

Comment: You need to use NTP to sync the time on the servers

Comment: @GariSingh Thankyou very much. This tip helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncing time in the multi-host network using ntp update helped me resolve the error. I used the below commands to sync the time.

```
sudo apt-get install ntpdate
sudo ntpdate 1.ro.pool.ntp.org
```