# Peer Channel Create in docker container fails with: identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm working through a [course](https://courses.btacertified.com/courses/Hyperledger-Fabric-v1-4-Architecting-Designing-and-Deploying-a-Network) at Blockchain Training Alliance for Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.*

I'm trying to start a channel on a dev test network and keep getting the following error:

```
2020-07-07 01:41:48.496 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 34f Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority) for identity 0
```

I saw in [one post by anjy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883465/principal-deserialization-failure-the-supplied-identity-is-not-valid-x509-cer) that network time-sync issues can cause this issue.  My time did seem to be different on the containers verses the host VM, so I installed `ntpdate` and ran `sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org` on host VM before starting the network.  That fixed the time issue, but the above error was still there.

According to [Nikhil Gupta's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662562/when-i-try-to-create-a-channel-using-hyperledger-fabric-the-request-fails/57662645#57662645), this error indicates that <s>"the MSP ID that was passed as a parameter with the request was not recognized by the ordering service."</s>
*"the ordering service recognized your MSP ID, but could not validate that your certificate was issued by one of your organization's certificate authorities."*

I'm using cryptogen and configtxgen to create my artifacts as follows:

```
$cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
```

then I edit docker-compose.yml to include the newly generated sk value and continue with:

```
$configtxgen -profile DefaultBlockOrderingService -outputBlock ./config/genesis.block -configPath $PWD

$configtxgen -profile btaMembersOnly -outputCreateChannelTx ./config/btamembersonly.tx -channelID btamembersonly
```

After succeeding to create the genesis block and channel transaction artifact, I start the network:

```
$docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d Devorderer.btacoin.com Andy.BTA.btacoin.com GeneralCA.btacoin.com cli

andy@ubuntu-server:~/fabric/network$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
f406f488ede5        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        4 seconds ago       Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   Andy.BTA.btacoin.com
0900795b1368        hyperledger/fabric-tools     "/bin/bash"              4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                                                         cli
c4946b315b08        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                6 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           Devorderer.btacoin.com
2e66b1d981f5        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   6 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           GeneralCA.btacoin.com
```

Then I log into the admin peer and try to start the channel:

```
$docker exec -it Andy.BTA.btacoin.com bash
#cd /etc/hyperledger/configtx
#export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=BTAMSP
#export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@BTA.btacoin.com/msp
#peer channel create -o Devorderer.btacoin.com:7050 -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/btamembersonly.tx -c btamembersonly
```

At this point, I get the following error:

```
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'btamembersonly', could not succesfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

At this point, the orderer node log shows the error mentioned at the beginning:

```
2020-07-07 01:57:04.947 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 34f Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority) for identity 0
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.947 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 350 0xc00046e820 gate 1594087024947536840 evaluation starts
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.947 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 351 0xc00046e820 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.947 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 352 0xc00046e820 principal evaluation fails
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.947 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 353 0xc00046e820 gate 1594087024947536840 evaluation fails
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.947 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 354 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/BTAMSP/Admins
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.947 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 355 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/BTAMSP/Admins
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.947 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 356 Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ BTAMSP/Admins ]
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.947 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 357 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/ChannelCreationPolicy
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.947 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 358 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/ChannelCreationPolicy
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.947 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 359 [channel: btamembersonly] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.18.0.4:56024 because of error: error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'btamembersonly', could not succesfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.947 UTC [orderer.common.server] func1 -> DEBU 35a Closing Broadcast stream
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.947 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 35b streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.4:56024 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=12.196088ms
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.960 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 35c Error reading from 172.18.0.4:56022: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.961 UTC [orderer.common.server] func1 -> DEBU 35d Closing Deliver stream
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.961 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 35e streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.4:56022 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=27.125361ms
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.964 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 35f transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
    2020-07-07 01:57:04.964 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 360 transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
```

I'm not really sure where to look next for troubleshooting.

My setup is as follows (please let me know if I missed any key information):

```
andy@ubuntu-server:~/fabric/network$ tree -L 2
.
├── config
│   ├── btamembersonly.tx
│   └── genesis.block
├── configtx.yaml
├── crypto-config
│   ├── ordererOrganizations
│   └── peerOrganizations
├── crypto-config.yaml
├── defaults
│   ├── core.yaml
│   └── orderer.yaml
└── docker-compose.yml
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
andy@ubuntu-server:~/fabric/network$ cat -n docker-compose.yml 
     1    version: '2'
     2
     3    networks:
     4      btacoin:
     5
     6    services:
     7      GeneralCA.btacoin.com:
     8        container_name: GeneralCA.btacoin.com
     9        image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    10        command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b btaCA:SimplePassword' #startup command
    11        environment:
    12          - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=GeneralCA.btacoin.com
    13          - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=debug
    14          - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    15          - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.BTA.btacoin.com-cert.pem
    16          - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ccb94b9473ef97a36b7d83beeb80583e9a2bda50ca5a392071b3c96185948ed7_sk
    17        volumes:
    18          - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/BTA.btacoin.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    19        ports:
    20          - 7054:7054
    21        networks:
    22          - btacoin
    23
    24      Devorderer.btacoin.com:
    25        container_name: Devorderer.btacoin.com
    26        image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    27        command: orderer  #startup command  
    28        environment:
    29          - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
    30          - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
    31          - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
    32          - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=debug         
    33          - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=btacoinOrderersMSP
    34          - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
    35          - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
    36
    37        volumes:
    38          - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    39          - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/btacoin.com/orderers/Devorderer.btacoin.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
    40          - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/BTA.btacoin.com/peers/Andy.BTA.btacoin.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/BTA
    41        ports:
    42          - 7050:7050
    43        networks:
    44          - btacoin
    45
    46      Andy.BTA.btacoin.com:
    47        container_name: Andy.BTA.btacoin.com
    48        image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    49        command: peer node start #startup command 
    50        environment:
    51            - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_btacoin
    52            - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
    53            - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=debug
    54            - CORE_PEER_ID=Andy.BTA.btacoin.com
    55            - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=Andy.BTA.btacoin.com:7051
    56            - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=BTAMSP
    57            - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
    58        
    59        volumes:
    60          - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    61          - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/BTA.btacoin.com/peers/Andy.BTA.btacoin.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
    62          - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/BTA.btacoin.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users      
    63          - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx      
    64          - ./../cc:/etc/hyperledger/chaincode 
    65          - ./chaincode:/etc/hyperledger/chaincode #Referenced in the Student Lab Guide
    66        ports: 
    67          - 7051:7051
    68          - 7053:7053
    69        depends_on:
    70          - Devorderer.btacoin.com
    71        networks:
    72          - btacoin
    73
    74      cli:
    75        container_name: cli
    76        image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    77        command: /bin/bash #startup command  
    78        tty: true
    79        environment:
    80          - GOPATH=/opt/gopath/src
    81          - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
    82          - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=debug
    83          - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
    84          - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=Andy.BTA.btacoin.com:7051
    85          - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=BTAMSP
    86          - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/BTA.btacoin.com/user/Admin@BTA.btacoin.com/msp
    87
    88        volumes:
    89          - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    90          - ./../cc/:/opt/gopath/src/
    91          - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    92  #       - ./cryptoconfig:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    93          - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    94        depends_on:
    95          - Devorderer.btacoin.com
    96        networks:
    97          - btacoin
```

**configtx.yaml**:

```
andy@ubuntu-server:~/fabric/network$ cat -n configtx.yaml 
     1  Organizations:
     2      - &btacoinOrderers
     3          Name: btacoinOrderersMSP
     4          ID: btacoinOrderersMSP
     5          MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/btacoin.com/msp
     6      - &BTA
     7          Name: BTAMSP 
     8          ID: BTAMSP
     9          MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/btacoin.com/msp
    10          AnchorPeers:
    11            - Host: Andy.BTA.btacoin.com
    12              Port: 7051
    13
    14  Application:  &ApplicationDefaults
    15      Organizations:
    16
    17  Orderer:  &DevModeOrdering
    18      OrdererType: solo
    19      Addresses: 
    20        - Devorderer.btacoin.com:7050
    21      BatchTimeout: 1s
    22      BatchSize: 
    23        MaxMessageCount: 1
    24
    25  Channel: 
    26
    27  Profiles:
    28    DefaultBlockOrderingService:
    29      Orderer:
    30        <<: *DevModeOrdering
    31        Organizations:
    32          - *btacoinOrderers
    33      Consortiums:
    34        NetworkConsortium: #Note, in the video, this was called SampleConsortium
    35          Organizations:
    36            - *BTA
    37    btaMembersOnly:
    38      Consortium: NetworkConsortium #Note, in the video, this was called SampleConsortium 
    39      Application:
    40        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
    41        Organizations:
    42          - *BTA
    43
```

**crypto-config.yaml**:

```
andy@ubuntu-server:~/fabric/network$ cat -n crypto-config.yaml 
     1  #Note: crypto-config is only used for development purposes, NOT for production purposes
     2  #For production, you should have the Certificate Authority manage things!
     3  OrdererOrgs:
     4    - Name: btacoinOrderers
     5      Domain: btacoin.com
     6      Specs: 
     7        - Hostname: Devorderer
     8
     9  PeerOrgs:
    10    - Name: BTA
    11      Domain: BTA.btacoin.com
    12      Specs: 
    13        - Hostname: Andy
    14      Template:
    15        Count: 1
    16      Users:
    17        Count: 1
```

**CA cert value used in docker-compose.yml:**

```
andy@ubuntu-server:~/fabric/network$ ls ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/BTA.btacoin.com/ca
ca.BTA.btacoin.com-cert.pem  ccb94b9473ef97a36b7d83beeb80583e9a2bda50ca5a392071b3c96185948ed7_sk
```

orderer.yaml and core.yaml come from:
https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/fabric-masterclass/orderer.yaml
https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/fabric-masterclass/core.yaml

Docker images come from:

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-orderer
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-ca
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-tools
```

*The course is self-guided and with no forum or course support available.  If there was another channel for help, I wouldn't post here.  (I tried emailing the course creators for help prior to posting here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the course creators sent me a copy of the official YAML files for comparison.  After comparing those files with mine, I discovered that **I entered the wrong MSP for the peer in configtx.yaml**.
Instead of pointing to the peer's MSP, I was pointing to the orderer's MSP!

Original (with error):

```
     6      - &BTA
     7          Name: BTAMSP 
     8          ID: BTAMSP
     9          MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/btacoin.com/msp
    10          AnchorPeers:
    11            - Host: Andy.BTA.btacoin.com
    12              Port: 7051
```

Corrected line:

```
     9          MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/BTA.btacoin.com/msp
```

After fixing this line, I was able to successfully create the new channel.

Answer (score 1):

> According to [Nikhil Gupta's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662562/when-i-try-to-create-a-channel-using-hyperledger-fabric-the-request-fails/57662645#57662645), this error indicates that "the MSP ID that was passed as a parameter with the request was not recognized by the ordering service."

Actually, this isn't true.  If you read this post carefully, you will see that the error

```
ERRO 02d Principal deserialization failure
(the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate usigned by unknown authority)
```

actually indicates that the MSPID *is* recognized by the system, and that in fact, it is your certificate which is invalid.  So, either the MSPID does not match the certificate, or, the certificate was not appropriately isseud by the CAs for that MSPID in your channel configuration.

In your case, based on the fact that this is a course exercise, and not a production network, I would guess that perhaps the network has been bootstrapped multiple times, but without properly cleaning all of the persisted artifacts in between steps.  I would encourage you to ensure that all docker containers and especially docker volumes have been removed, and attempt to recreate this failure in a clean environment.  The docker-compose you included does enumerate volumes, you can see them via `docker volume ls`, and you can remove them with a command like `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)`.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thank you for your feedback and for pointing out my mis-interpretation of Nikhil Gupta's post!    
As for leftover artifacts, before retesting, I brought everything down by : (1) `docker stop $(docker ps -aq)`, (2) `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`, (3) `docker rmi $(docker images -q)`, and re-pulled the images before bringing everything back up.  (I did this a few times before my original post.)    
The course creators just emailed me back with the "official" YAML files, so I'm going to scour those for any differences from mine and report back if I find the answer.

Comment: Note that your docker compose file defines volumes, which you are not cleaning up.  You can see them with `docker volume ls` and remove them with `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)`, updating answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you again for explaining this to me!  I've got a lot to learn, and these pointers really help.  Based on your feedback, I'm going to spend some more time studying docker usage.  I finished combing through the YAML files and found the culprit.  I used the wrong MSP for the peer in configtx.yaml (line 9).  After fixing that line (to point to the correct peer MSP), I was able to successfully create the channel block.